# How do I make a decorator to wrap an async function with a try except statement?

Tags: python

Let's say I have an async function like this:

```
async def foobar(argOne, argTwo, argThree):
   print(argOne, argTwo, argThree)
```

I want to make a decorator and use it on this function in a way that it wraps the above code in a try except statement like this:

```
try:
   print(argOne, argTwo, argThree)
except:
   print('Something went wrong.)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

because wrapper called first, we should also define it as a async function: `async def wrap(*arg, **kwargs):`

```python
import asyncio

def decorator(f):
    async def wrapper(*arg, **kwargs):
        try:
            await f(*arg, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Something went wrong.', e)
    return wrapper


@decorator
async def foobar(argOne, argTwo, argThree):
    print(argOne, argTwo, argThree)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

asyncio.run(foobar("a", "b", "c"))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, **[including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) really helps to improve the quality of your post**. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

```
def deco(coro1):
    async def coro2(argOne, argTwo, argThree):
        try:
            await coro1(argOne, argTwo, argThree)
        except:
            print('Something went wrong.')
    return coro2

@deco
async def foobar(argOne, argTwo, argThree):
    print(argOne, argTwo, argThree)
```

Comment: While this code may be useful to the OP, providing [additional context](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/90527) regarding why & how it works, and when it should be used will improve its long-term value by helping other readers.